# How to add multiple columns in a row of an android table layout

Tags: android

I have a custom list with name,age and grade .I want to loop through the list and show the contents in a table layout.Each row  will have following attributes.Row will have some kind of styling

```
  Name,
   Age,
   Age_Value,
   Grade,
   Grade_Value
```

Here Age and Grades are just a label.Given below is a sample table

```
Dolly
Age
23
Grade
A+

Roman
Age
22
Grade 
C

Ben
Age
23
Grade
B+
```

I want to add these details to the Table layout in my layout dynamically.

Here is the code im trying

```
 for(int j=0;j<_attributeList.size();j++)
                      {

                          TableRow tr = new TableRow(MyActivity.this);
                          tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                              TextView tvName = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                              tvName.setPadding(3,0,0,0);
                              tvName.setText(_attributeList.get(j).getName() +" : ");
                              tr.addView(tvName);

                              TextView tvAgeL = new TextView(MyActivity.this);

                              tvAgeL .setText("Age");
                              tr.addView(tvAgeL );

                              TextView tvAgeValue = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                              tvAgeValue .setPadding(3,0,0,0);
                              tvAgeValue .setText(_attributeList.get(j).getValue() +" : ");
                              tr.addView(tvAgeValue );



                          attributeTable.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                     }
                    }
```

Since these items are adding to the same row im getting results in a single line. How can i show them in seperate rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try like this

**Code**

```
for(int i = 0; i < _attributeList.size();i++){              

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    newCheckBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());

    TextView feeTypeText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    feeTypeText.setText(jsonObj.getString("feeType"));
    feeTypeText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    feeTypeText.setTextSize(16f);
    feeTypeText.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView dueAmountText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    dueAmountText.setText(jsonObj.getString("dueAmount"));
    dueAmountText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    dueAmountText.setTextSize(16f);
    dueAmountText.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView dueDateText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    dueDateText.setText(jsonObj.getString("dueDate"));
    dueDateText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    dueDateText.setTextSize(16f);
    dueDateText.setTypeface(tf);

    newRow.addView(newCheckBox,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f)));
    newRow.addView(feeTypeText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f)));
    newRow.addView(dueAmountText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f)));
    newRow.addView(dueDateText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f)));
    attributeTable.addView(newRow);
}
```

Comment: newRow.addView(feeTypeText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f))); ..The constructor ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int, int, float) is undefined   .am i missing somthing?

Comment: I used some linear layouts  to acheive the result.Your code really helped.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can add like this way...here i added TableRow Programatically in which i added textView.

```
addtree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {


                tr1 = new TableRow(YourActivity.this);
                tr1.setClickable(true);
                tr1.setId(jj);
                tr1.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
                Log.d("id", "id is......"+tr1.getId());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                TextView textview = new TextView(New_Quote_Activity.this);

                textview.setText("Job "+jj);
                textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                textview.setTextSize(14);
                textview.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);


                View vv=new View(New_Quote_Activity.this);
                vv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1));

                vv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.viewcolor);

                View vv1=new View(New_Quote_Activity.this);
                vv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1));

                vv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.viewcolor);
                tr1.addView(textview);

                table_crete_invoice.addView(vv1);
                table_crete_invoice.addView(tr1,layoutParams);
                table_crete_invoice.addView(vv);


            }
```